# Python / MT5, how to close half a position?

Tags: metatrader5

I am opening an Buy order with:

```
   price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol_for_strategy).ask
   stop_loss = price - price/2
   take_profit = price + price/2
   request = {
        "action": MetaTrader5.TRADE_ACTION_DEAL,
        "symbol": "BTCUSD",
        "volume": 0.01,
        "type": mt5.ORDER_TYPE_BUY,
        "price": round(price, 3),
        "sl": round(stop_loss, 3),
        "tp": round(take_profit, 3),
        "type_filling": MetaTrader5.ORDER_FILLING_IOC,
        "type_time": MetaTrader5.ORDER_TIME_GTC,
        "comment": "JustBought"
    }
```

I receive this response:

```
OrderSendResult(retcode=10009, deal=32053541, order=36382142, volume=0.01, price=27387.84, bid=0.0, ask=0.0, comment='Request executed', request_id=185019985, retcode_external=0, request=TradeRequest(action=1, magic=0, order=0, symbol='BTCUSD', volume=0.01, price=27387.84, stoplimit=0.0, sl=13693.92, tp=41081.76, deviation=0, type=0, type_filling=1, type_time=0, expiration=0, comment='JustBought', position=0, position_by=0))
```

Then, I am sending a close order with:

```
request = {
    "action": MetaTrader5.TRADE_ACTION_CLOSE_BY,
    "position": 36382142,
    "symbol": "BTCUSD",
    "volume": 0.005,
}
```

Where "position" is the number of the buy order...

And I receive an error:

```
OrderSendResult(retcode=10013, deal=0, order=0, volume=0.0, price=0.0, bid=0.0, ask=0.0, comment='Invalid request', request_id=0, retcode_external=0, request=TradeRequest(action=10, magic=0, order=0, symbol='BTCUSD', volume=0.005, price=0.0, stoplimit=0.0, sl=0.0, tp=0.0, deviation=0, type=0, type_filling=0, type_time=0, expiration=0, comment='', position=36382142, position_by=0))
```

Any idea why I am getting this "Invalid request" error ?

Thanks